# Running using Python command: python , ImportError: No module named pyproj

Tags: python, module, pyproj

[image]

Hi, it is my first time asking question on StackOverflow. 
First, I am trying to use openSFM but it is really hard. As in the picture 
I wrote command  `bin/opensfm_run_all data/berlin`

but the error keeps coming out like this:

Running using Python command: python

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/yjw/OpenSfM/bin/opensfm", line 10, in <module>
    from opensfm import commands
  File "/home/yjw/OpenSfM/opensfm/commands/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import extract_metadata
  File "/home/yjw/OpenSfM/opensfm/commands/extract_metadata.py", line 5, in <module>
    from opensfm import dataset
  File "/home/yjw/OpenSfM/opensfm/dataset.py", line 12, in <module>
    from opensfm import io
  File "/home/yjw/OpenSfM/opensfm/io.py", line 15, in <module>
    import pyproj
ImportError: No module named pyproj
```

I did install `pyproj` by using `pip3 install pyproj` 
but I really don't know what the problem is. Can someone help me, please??
Thanks is advance.

Comment: Which python version you're using? Python 2 or 3?
Try this too, pip install pyproj

Comment: I use python3. I tried both pip install pyproj  and pip3 install pyproj and it worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on Python version (2,3) you need to install package using pip2 or pip3. 'pip' can be either of the two depending on the system.
Install pyproj of same python as the script which is using pyproj is based upon. If main script is python2 install pyproj using pip2 etc.
Try going into the python shell or ipython shell . Just type 'python2' or 'python3' in command line. 
In python shell try importing and testing first.
For systems which doesn't have root access. Try using a virtual environment and installing all packages there. Will avoid any such import errors.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html